# Mac OS xargs combine original argument with new arguments

Tags: xargs, macos

I am able to list audio files with the complete path: (using '-onlyin' for testing)

```
$ mdfind -0 -onlyin ~/Music kind:audio | xargs -0 -n 1
    /Users/rrasch/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music/Unknown Artist/Unknown Album/1998-04-29_OB07264seg6of6_Z86.wav
    /Users/rrasch/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music/Unknown Artist/Unknown Album/1998-04-29_OB07264seg4of6_Z86.wav
    /Users/rrasch/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music/Unknown Artist/Unknown Album/1998-04-29_OB07264seg1of6_Z86.wav
    /Users/rrasch/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music/Unknown Artist/Unknown Album/1993-11-04_illiteracy_laura_jaeger_jim_latemer_2448.wav
```

I am also able to get the bit depth and sample rate by running mdls as an argument in xargs:

```
$ mdfind -0 -onlyin ~/Music kind:audio | xargs -0 mdls -name kMDItemAudioSampleRate -name kMDItemBitsPerSample -raw | xargs -0 -n 2
    44100 24
    44100 24
    44100 24
    48000 24
```

If I add kMDItemFSName to the mdls I can get the filename along with bit depth and sample rate but I lose the path:

```
$ mdfind -0 -onlyin ~/Music kind:audio | xargs -0 mdls -name kMDItemAudioSampleRate -name kMDItemBitsPerSample -name kMDItemFSName -raw | xargs -0 -n 3
44100 24 1998-04-29_OB07264seg6of6_Z86.wav
44100 24 1998-04-29_OB07264seg4of6_Z86.wav
44100 24 1998-04-29_OB07264seg1of6_Z86.wav
48000 24 1993-11-04_illiteracy_laura_jaeger_jim_latemer_2448.wav
```

I want to scan for audio in multiple directories (I will omit '-onlyin' when I deploy) How do I list the full path with bit depth and sample rate...like this:

```
44100 24 /Users/rrasch/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music/Unknown Artist/Unknown Album/1998-04-29_OB07264seg6of6_Z86.wav
44100 24 /Users/rrasch/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music/Unknown Artist/Unknown Album/1998-04-29_OB07264seg4of6_Z86.wav
44100 24 /Users/rrasch/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music/Unknown Artist/Unknown Album/1998-04-29_OB07264seg1of6_Z86.wav
48000 24 /Users/rrasch/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music/Unknown Artist/Unknown Album/1993-11-04_illiteracy_laura_jaeger_jim_latemer_2448.wav
```

Comment: According to [Spotlight Metadata Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreServices/Reference/MetadataAttributesRef/Reference/CommonAttrs.html), there should also be a `kMDItemPath` - does that help?

Answer (score 0):

I used gfind (brew install findutils) to achieve similar to above:

```
$ gfind /tmp/temp -iname "*.mp4" -printf '\n' -exec ls {} \; -exec mdls -name kMDItemAudioSampleRate -name kMDItemBitsPerSample -raw {} \; | xargs -0 -n 2 

/tmp/temp/a.mp4
(null) (null)
/tmp/temp/b.mp4
(null)
(null)
/tmp/temp/c.mp4
(null) (null)
/tmp/temp/d.mp4
(null)
(null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Call a short in-line script from `xargs`:

```
mdfind -0 -onlyin ~/Music kind:audio | xargs -0 sh -c '
for pathname do
    printf "%s %s %s\n" \
        "$( mdls -name kMDItemAudioSampleRate -raw "$pathname" )" \
        "$( mdls -name kMDItemBitsPerSample   -raw "$pathname" )" \
        "$pathname"
done' sh
```

The loop receives batches of found pathnames from `mdfind`.  For each pathname, `mdls` is used to extract the two attributes that you are interested in, and the values of these are printed together with the pathname itself using `printf`.

Or, try using the `kMDItemPath` attribute, which would allow you to call `mdls` only once per pathname:

```
mdfind -0 -onlyin ~/Music kind:audio | xargs -0 sh -c '
for pathname do
    mdls -name kMDItemAudioSampleRate \
         -name kMDItemBitsPerSample \
         -name kMDItemPath \
         -raw "$pathname" | tr "\0" " "
    echo
done' sh
```